# Can my OAuth2 client also emit its own access tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Our application is already a client delegating into several Authorization Servers. The point is that we have user accounts, but we don't store any credentials. Our users come authenticated from Facebook / Google / etc, and their local account is created automatically.

Now, as this application has grown other applications want to integrate with our API, and thus we want to offer our own OAuth2 endpoints. We are implementing a full-blown OAuth2 server, keeping the part delegated to Facebook/Google/whatnot, and otherwise working as a normal server (emitting our own access tokens, refresh tokens, etc). Is that the expected thing to do? Is there anything in the standard specific to this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is normal. Today you implement the Resource Server and Google etc. are the Authorization Servers. You are planning to implement a new Authorization Server. Logically, this will be completely distinct from the Resource Server, even though it *may* be located on the same physical server.

However, implementing an Authorization Server is relatively complex because it is intended to support multiple, independent clients. If you don't want to support other, 3rd party clients you could choose a simpler membership provider type model for your own authentication and keep the OAuth parts for the external authentication providers. That is, just have a sign-in page in your application, keep the usernames and hashed credentials in your DB and use application sessions. Provide some UI to let the user choose between signing in "natively" using your membership provider, or using an external one.

Lots of sites take this dual approach (e.g. StackOverflow itself - you can sign in with Facebook or a SO account). It will be less effort than a full blown OAuth 2 authorization server.

Comment: Yep, we were doing that until third parties started asking to integrate their systems using our API. That required us to walk the extra mile to become an OAuth provider ourselves.

Comment: Good luck! There are starting to be some decent products out there to build on (e.g. ThinkTexture IdentityServer if you are on .Net)